# Css and Javascript Make a scroll div using position absolut and relative

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

After using only "pre make" compoments like Mui or TailWind I try to do a component using only CSS and maybe JavaScritp. But i get some problems when i use relative and absolute positions to make a div go inside an image. I know that absolute positions broke the natural flow... and i need a way to make this scroll-div work.

The problem: when the page width is less then sum of all images the imagens overflow the next div aside. They don't respect the margins won by another div.

I think a solution as useRef to get the width from 'a' tag and calc the left position that go use to get a gap. Like left: 0, left: 580*funcGetWidthFromRef(), left:funcGetWidthFromRef().

Is there another solution?

My code:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../../styles/Card.module.css";
export default function Card() {
    const listArticles = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    const textTitle = ["Vant", "Vam", "Puits", "JUmpP"];
    return (
        <>
            {" "}
            <section className={`${styles.scrollableCategoryContent}`}>
                {listArticles.map((art, index) => {
                    return (
                        <article key={index} className={`styles.Game${art}`}>
                            <a
                                href=""
                                className={`${styles.cardAnchorConteirner}`}
                                style={{
                                    left: `${170 * index}px`,
                                    // width: `${580 * 4}px`,
                                    // maxWidth: `${700}px`,
                                }}
                            >
                                <Image
                                    // fill
                                    className={`${styles.cardImage}`}
                                    width={580}
                                    height={480}
                                    objectFit="cover"
                                    objectPosition="top left"
                                    src={
                                        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Postgres_Query.jpg/1920px-Postgres_Query.jpg"
                                    }
                                    alt="test"
                                ></Image>
                                <div
                                    className={`${styles.textCardBackGround}`}
                                    // style={{
                                    //     backgroundColor: `rgb(${
                                    //         0 + index * 10
                                    //     },${0 + index * 5 * 2},${
                                    //         0 - (index * 10) / 2
                                    //     },30%)`,
                                    // }}
                                >
                                    <h2
                                        className={`${styles.cardTitleText}`}
                                    >{`${textTitle[index]}`}</h2>
                                </div>

                                {/* card.{index} */}
                            </a>
                        </article>
                    );
                })}
            </section>
        </>
    );
}




.scrollableCategoryContent{
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  background-color: black;
  max-width: 700;
  height: 480px;
  overflow-x: scroll;


}

.Game1, .Game2, .Game3, .Game4 {
  
}

.cardAnchorConteirner{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* left: 100px;
  display: inline-block; */
  position: relative;
  
}

.cardImage{
  position: absolute;
  /* position: relative; */
}
.textCardBackGround {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: aqua;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 20%;



}
.cardTitleText{

  color: white;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution: Just put a div outside all relative and absolute positions divs... that div without positions can get Grid and then make possible to follow the normal flow.
If the div or other component have zero width or height the problem occurs.
I tried before this using UseRef... and get good results, but the code the code is gigantic if i try to implement another solutions on space like resize the image.

```
    import Image from "next/image";
    import styles from "../../styles/CardAlt.module.css";
    export default function CarCompAlt() {
        const games = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        const titles = ["Valorant", "Mw2", "RPGs", "Actions"];
    
        return (
            <>
                <section className={`${styles.trywarp}`}>
                    {/* <div className={`${styles.blablabla}`}>
                        Opa aoidaiwpdhipawipdajd dawuodhawhdhpadpwadad
                        awdouawhdhuwahduhwapida awdihahidahipdaipwdpwadipwa
                        huidhahwpdhipawdhawpidphiawdhipa awdipahdipahpidawdwadwad
                    </div> */}
                    {games.map((value, index) => {
                        return (
                            <article
                                key={index}
                                className={`${styles.thisJustWork}`}
                            >
                                <a
                                    href=""
                                    className={`${styles.cardArchorContainer}`}
                                >
                                    <Image
                                        className={`${styles.imageContainer}`}
                                        src={
                                            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Postgres_Query.jpg/1920px-Postgres_Query.jpg"
                                        }
                                        width={584}
                                        height={480}
                                        alt={`${2265}`}
                                        objectFit="cover"
                                        objectPosition="center"
                                    ></Image>
                                    <h3 className={`${styles.titleContainer}`}>
                                        {titles[index]}
                                    </h3>
                                </a>
                            </article>
                        );
                    })}
                </section>
            </>
        );
    }




CSS

    .trywarp{
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-flow: column;
        gap: 100px;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: clip;
    }
    .thisJustWork{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: brown;
    }
    
    .CardWarp{
    
    }



    
    .cardArchorContainer{
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .imageContainer{
        position: absolute;
    }
    .titleContainer{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 50;
        color: aliceblue;
    }
```

**The "try hard" solution using useRef but i have to give a width to "scrollableCategoryContent" to make the gap stop increase.**

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { HtmlHTMLAttributes, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import styles from "../../styles/Card.module.css";
export default function Card() {
    const refScrollableCategoryContent = useRef<any>();
    const [pixelGain, setPixelGain] = useState<number>(0);
    const [widhtScrollable, setSidhtScrollable] = useState<any>(
        refScrollableCategoryContent.current?.getBoundingClientRect().width
    );
    const listArticles = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    const textTitle = ["Vant", "Vam", "Puits", "JUmpP"];

    function reSizeScrollAble() {
        const widthRfScroll =
            refScrollableCategoryContent.current?.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        setSidhtScrollable(widthRfScroll);
        // setPixelGain(widthRfScroll - 700);
        // widthRfScroll - 700 >= 0
        //     ? setPixelGain(widthRfScroll - 700)
        //     : setPixelGain(0);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("window size onex : ", window);

        window.addEventListener("resize", reSizeScrollAble);
        reSizeScrollAble();
        console.log("windows size:", widhtScrollable);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", reSizeScrollAble);
        };
    }, []);

    // In this compoent I need to get the predominant color, but
    //don't have now and it is no safe npm or a code in javascript that fast.
    //So need to implement a endpoint on Docker using Python to make this
    //math and return fast results. Or simple write one time on firebase
    //this final result. For now only fixed colors
    return (
        <>
            {" "}
            <div>
                <div>Size window: {widhtScrollable}</div>
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                        setSidhtScrollable(
                            refScrollableCategoryContent.current?.getBoundingClientRect()

                            //offsetWidth and offsetHeight
                        );
                        console.log(
                            refScrollableCategoryContent.current?.getBoundingClientRect()
                                .width
                        );
                    }}
                >
                    refScrollableCategoryContent
                </button>
            </div>
            <section
                className={`${styles.scrollableCategoryContent}`}
                ref={refScrollableCategoryContent}
                // style={{
                //     width: "700px",
                // }}
            >
                {listArticles.map((art, index) => {
                    return (
                        <article key={index} className={`styles.Game${art}`}>
                            <a
                                href=""
                                className={`${styles.cardAnchorConteirner}`}
                                // style={{
                                //     left: `${(425 + pixelGain) * index}px`,
                                // }}
                                style={{
                                    left: `${(425 + pixelGain) * index}px`,
                                }}
                            >
                                {/* <div
                                    //just to clip width?
                                    style={{
                                        position: "absolute",
                                        overflowX: "clip",
                                        width: `${584 + pixelGain}px`,
                                        height: `${480}px`,
                                        backgroundColor: "aqua",
                                    }}
                                > */}
                                <Image
                                    // fill
                                    className={`${styles.cardImage}`}
                                    // style={{ width: `${584 - pixelGain}px` }}
                                    // width={584 + pixelGain}
                                    // height={480 + pixelGain}
                                    width={584}
                                    height={480}
                                    objectFit="cover"
                                    objectPosition="center"
                                    src={
                                        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Postgres_Query.jpg/1920px-Postgres_Query.jpg"
                                    }
                                    alt="test"
                                ></Image>
                                {/* </div> */}

                                <div
                                    className={`${styles.textCardBackGround}`}
                                    // style={{
                                    //     backgroundColor: `rgb(${
                                    //         0 + index * 10
                                    //     },${0 + index * 5 * 2},${
                                    //         0 - (index * 10) / 2
                                    //     },30%)`,
                                    // }}
                                >
                                    <h2
                                        className={`${styles.cardTitleText}`}
                                    >{`${textTitle[index]}`}</h2>
                                </div>

                                {/* card.{index} */}
                            </a>
                        </article>
                    );
                })}
            </section>
        </>
    );
}
```

CSS

```
.scrollableCategoryContent{
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  background-color: black;
  /* gap: 55%; */
  /* max-width: 200px; */
  width: 1000px;
  height: 480px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: clip;
  /* overflow-y: hidden; */
  /* position: relative; */
  
}

.Game1, .Game2, .Game3, .Game4 {
  
  /* position: relative;
  background-color: crimson;
  white-space: nowrap; */
}
/* 
.Game1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
.Game2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 580px ;
} */

.cardAnchorConteirner{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* left: 100px;
  display: inline-block; */
  position: relative;
  
}

.cardImage{
  position: absolute;
  /* overflow: clip; */
  /* position: relative; */
}
.textCardBackGround {
  position: absolute;
  /* padding: 0px;
 bottom: 10px;
 margin: 0px; */
 background-color: aqua;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 20%;

 /* position: absolute; */

}
.cardTitleText{
  /* position: absolute; */
  color: white;
  
}
```